# BATCH File to Remove Config File Entry

Tags: batch-file, configuration-files

**Basically:**

First time poster here...  I have been searching not only SO, but the entire internet for an answer for the last 2 days.  I am wanting to have a batch file( .bat ), that runs during an uninstall, open a config( .cfg ) file, find an entry, and remove it, then finish the uninstall.

**What I have so far:**

I have a Installer that runs a Batch file to add the entry into the config file:

```
[Area.01]
Title=Unique to entry
Location=Unique to entry
Active=Required but in all entries
Layer=Required with Unique Number
Required=Required but in all entries

[Area.02]
Title=Unique to entry
Location=Unique to entry
Active=Required but in all entries
Layer=Required with Unique Number
Required=Required but in all entries
```

I have the Install Batch file scan the config and add the next entry number, the content of the Entry, and a REGISTRY key that saves the index of the entry; so logically the next entry would be `[Area.03]`.  However this file contains over 100 entries.

What I want is for the batch file to read the registry entry, **which it does**, find the entry, **which it does**, and remove the entire entry, **which is why I am here**.  Here is what I have so far:

```
@echo off

REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Name of File" /v SceneryCFGPath
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO ERROR1
FOR /F "tokens=3 skip=2" %%i IN ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Name of File" /v SceneryCFGPath') DO SET VAR1=%%i
CD "%VAR1%"

REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Name of File" /v SceneryIndex
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO ERROR2
FOR /F "tokens=3 skip=2" %%i IN ('REG QUERY "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Name of File" /v SceneryIndex') DO SET VAR2=%%i
TYPE scenery.cfg | FINDSTR /V Area.%VAR2%
REG DELETE "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Name of File" /F
GOTO END

:ERROR1
ECHO There was an Error while changing to Directory "%VAR1%"...
PAUSE
GOTO ERROR2

:ERROR2
ECHO There was an Error while unregistering from Scenery Library ! Please delete the Area manually...
PAUSE
GOTO END

:END
del "%~f0"
```

When using the `FINDSTR` it successfully finds the entry, but **ONLY** removes the fist line: `[Area.03]`.  What I need it to do is remove that and the other portions of that entry.

When I tried to include the other entries in the FINDSTR:

`TYPE scenery.cfg | FINDSTR /V /N Area.%VAR2% | Title | Active | Layer | Required`

it removes **ALL** of those lines for every entry.

**I really prefer this to be a batch file, as this will run on Windows XP, Vista and 7, 32 and 64 Bit systems.**  As these particular Windows Systems all have **CMD.EXE**, there would be no need for any additional libraries or programs.

I have everything working perfectly, **EXCEPT** removing the whole entry in the config file.  I hope I did not confuse anyone, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Sven2157

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before solving the problem you asked, there are some other issues to deal with concerning your error handling.

You test to see if a particular registry key value exists, and if not found you attempt to print out the key value that doesn't exist! That doesn't work ;-)

You attempt to CD to the found path value, but there is no guarantee that the path is valid. You probably want to check for an error. Also, the current drive may not match the drive of the path, so you should use CD /D (or PUSHD).

You use 2 REG QUERY ops per registry key value pair - one to test for existence and another to parse the value. You should only need 1 REG QUERY per key value.

The batch file is deleting itself when finished. This will cause a "The batch file cannot be found" error. Perhaps you don't care, but you probably should redirect stdout to nul when you call this batch.

Since your batch file kills itself with the deletion, you can simplify your error handling. No need for a separate routine for each error. Simply  CALL a generic error routine, passing in the error message. The error routine can fall through to the end routine when done, which kills the batch. So there is no need to worry about returning from the error call.

I've incorporated all the above ideas into my code below.

I've also assumed you actually want to modify the "scenery.cfg" file, and not simply echo the changed form to the screen. I redirect the output to a new file, then rename the new file to the old name, thus destroying the original.

Now, to get to your original question - batch does not have any native utility that will conveniently extract a range of lines between two marker lines. Since you don't want to rely on any non-native utilities, you will have to process each line in a loop and determine if the line should be included or not.

I see 2 simple ways to do this: *Note - none of the code has been tested. The concepts are all sound, but I may have introduced a silly bug that should be easy to fix*

**1 - Use a single loop to examine each line and begin excluding the line when the selected area is found and resume when the next area starts**

The code uses SET search and replace to test to see if the line contains the string in question.

The classic technique for reading a file is the FOR /F loop. But it strips out blank lines. So the code is extended to add a blank line before each [Area.nn] section. Delayed expansion is needed, but FOR variable values containing `!` are corrupted if delayed expansion is enabled. So I toggle delayed expansion on and off within the loop. If you know that `!` will never appear in the file, then you can simply enable delayed expansion at the top and remove the SET LOCAL and ENDLOCAL from within the loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set regPath="HKLM\SOFTWARE\Name of File"

set "myPath="
for /f "tokens=3 skip=2" %%A in ('reg query %regPath% /v SceneryCFGPath') do set "myPath=%%A"
if not defined myPath call :error Unable to locate SceneryCFGPath
cd /d "%myPath%" 2>nul || call :error Unable to CD to "%myPath%"

set "area="
for /f "tokens=3 skip=2" %%A IN ('reg query %regPath% /v SceneryIndex') do set "area=%%A"
if not defined area call :error Unable to unregister from Scenery Library ! Please delete the Area manually...

>scenery.cfg.new (
  set "del="
  for /f "delims=" %%A in (scenery.cfg) do (
    set "ln=%%A"
    setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
    if "!ln:[Area.%area%=!" neq "!ln!" (
        set del=1
    ) else if "!ln:[Area.=!" neq "!ln!" (
        set "del="
        echo(
    )
    if not defined del echo !ln!
    endlocal
  )
)
move /y scenery.cfg.new scenery.cfg

reg delete %regPath% /f
goto end

:error
echo ERROR: %*
pause

:end
del "%~f0"
```

**2 - Use FINDSTR to find the beginning of the selected area, and a 2nd FINDSTR to find the beginning of the next area.**

The /N option is used to get the line number of the matching line. FOR /F is used to parse and assign the result to a value. GOTO is required to break out of the 2nd loop once the next area is found.

Finally a 3rd FOR /F is used to read the file that has line numbers prepended by a FINDSTR command. Each line is parsed and the appropriate lines are excluded.

Note that this code does not work properly if a line begins with `:`. The limitation can be removed with a bit more code, but I don't think it is needed in your case.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set regPath="HKLM\SOFTWARE\Name of File"

set "myPath="
for /f "tokens=3 skip=2" %%A in ('reg query %regPath% /v SceneryCFGPath') do set "myPath=%%A"
if not defined myPath call :error Unable to locate SceneryCFGPath
cd /d "%myPath%" 2>nul || call :error Unable to CD to "%myPath%"

set "area="
for /f "tokens=3 skip=2" %%A IN ('reg query %regPath% /v SceneryIndex') do set "area=%%A"
if not defined area call :error Unable to unregister from Scenery Library ! Please delete the Area manually...

set "beginDel="
for /f "delims=:" %%N in ('findstr /nbc:"[Area.%area%]" scenery.cfg') do set beginDel=%%N
if not defined beginDel goto end

set "endDel="
for /f "delims=:" %%N in ('findstr /nbc:"[Area." scenery.cfg') do if %%N gtr beginDel (
  set endCond=if %%A gre %%N
  goto :break
)
:break

>scenery.cfg.new (
  for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" scenery.cfg') do (
    if %%A lss %beginDel% %endCond% echo(%%B
  )
)
move /y scenery.cfg.new scenery.cfg

reg delete %regPath% /f
goto end

:error
echo ERROR: %*
pause

:end
del "%~f0"
```

Comment: THANK YOU SIR! The FINDSTR( #2 ) Method, worked like a charm and was the one I went with.  I will have to have some friends test this using their environments, but this is exactly what I needed!